How to check if a given value exists in list of constants
I have a class called Department which contains some constants, I need a method to check if a given value exists in this constants list.
public static class Department
{
  #region Public Constants
   
    public const int Paperback = 1;
    public const int Hardcover = 2;
    public const int Music = 3;

  #endregion
}

Now in another class I'm using or verify/passing values like below the value.
int? Dept = 4;
var availableDepartment= Department.Exists(Dept.Value);

Here availableDepartment should return false since 4 does not exists as department Constants.
I'm looking for an Exists method in class to check if value 4 exists as constants or not.
Please someone help on this.

Could you use an enum instead of a bunch of const int?

Use an enum instead

@KlausGütter, I know that solution , due to existing framework restriction , I cannot change that to enum.  else s many changes will be there. any other solution with these list of constants.

even i can use reflection like this
var obj =  typeof(Department)
.GetFields(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy);
                        var value = obj.GetValue(constantValue);   but not sure this is right way to do , it will throw exception when it is not found


Using reflection for this sounds like trying to invent a new generation of the JWST telescope just for spying on your neighbor when she gets out of the shower. LOL

As mentioned by others, using reflection is quite an overkill and this problem can be solved in other ways.
However if for some reason you cannot use the other methods, and you must use reflection (since you explicitly tagged system.reflection), here is a way to do this:
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;

namespace Test
{
    public class Util
    {
        // Get the public constants of a type:
        public static List<FieldInfo> GetPublicConstants(Type type)
        {
            FieldInfo[] fieldInfos = type.GetFields(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy);
            return fieldInfos.Where(fi => fi.IsLiteral && !fi.IsInitOnly).ToList();
        }
    }
        
    public static class Department
    {
        public const int Paperback = 1;
        public const int Hardcover = 2;
        public const int Music = 3;

        public static bool Exists(int departmentNum)
        {
            var constants = Util.GetPublicConstants(typeof(Department));
            foreach (var constant in constants)
            {
                if ((int)constant.GetRawConstantValue() == departmentNum)
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        private static void CheckDepartment(int departmentNum)
        {
            bool bExists = Department.Exists(departmentNum);
            Console.WriteLine("Department {0} exists: {1}", departmentNum,  bExists ? "yes" : "no");
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CheckDepartment(1);
            CheckDepartment(4);
        }
    }
}

Output:
Department 1 exists: yes
Department 4 exists: no

Notes:

class Util with the method GetPublicConstants is general and can be used for any type.
In Department.Exists method I assumed all the constants are ints, if this is not the actual case you need to cast the value to the proper type.
The usage of Department.Exists is demostrated in the test method CheckDepartment.

Live demo

Thanks for the solution along with the explanation @wohlstad.  I know enum will be best option but what I was looking is the one you provided, Thanks! :-)

Happy to help and thanks for accepting my answer @Sandy. Just in case you are not aware: in addition you can also upvote it (you can upvote all useful answers), as accepting and voting is separate. See: What should I do when someone answers my question?.

If you can't use enum (which nonetheless should be the preferred way of doing such things), how about the straight forward way of implementing a static method in the static class Department? No need for reflection, because if you add an additional value to the Department class you can also adapt the Exists method ...
public static class Department {

  public const int Paperback = 1;
  public const int Hardcover = 2;
  public const int Music = 3;
  
  public static bool Exists(int val) {
    return val == Paperback || val == Hardcover || val == Music;
  }
}

which you then can call via
Department.Exists(3);  //returns true
Department.Exists(27); //returns false

See also this fiddle

You can use an enum and set it to your constants.
public static class Department {

    private enum DepartmentEnum
    {
        Paperback = 1,
        Hardcover = 2,
        Music = 3,
    }

    public const int Paperback = (int)DepartmentEnum.Paperback;
    public const int Hardcover = (int)DepartmentEnum.Hardcover;
    public const int Music = (int)DepartmentEnum.Music;
  
    public static bool Exists(int value) {
        return Enum.IsDefined<DepartmentEnum>(value);
    }

}

This solution relies on you defining each constant both in the class and in the enum. I don't know what is your use case nor the reason for your constraint on not using enums, but this should work, unless you have some other constraint you did not mention in the question.

If you need the constant anyways, why would you need to define an additional enum?

@derpirscher It's just an alternative to checking each constant in an || (or) expression, in case you have a lot of constants you need to check. Anyway, I don't know why the OP can't use enums, as I never saw such a case, but this is just an alternative approach. The approach you posted is much simpler, and I would prefer it, but I also thought of adding an alternative, to demonstrate how it is done with enums.

Another alternative approach would be to have all constants have sequential values (for example, starting at 1) and then check if the value is between the range of valid values (for example return value >= 1 && value <= 3).

correct checking the range is another way to solve, that was existing solution a IsBetween extension method I created but changing that due to some other reason. I have  legacy WPF application with rigid architecture. anyway thanks for your input
